# Drupal 8 - Filter a view for specific user to match the content related field with username

Tags: view, drupal-8, content-type

I am not a drupal expert but i want to build a retail system on drupal 8.

Please see the scenario below with what i want to achieve and what i have done so far.

I want to build a system for all the retail stores, so they can login and see the online orders specific to their users. However each store has a single username.

What i have done: i have created a content type called "Orders" for orders and put following fields (Text plain fields) for testing:

1- OrderID

2- StoreID (exact similar to the user name. for example user1234)

3- ProductName

i have a feeds module, which will load the data from the CSV file and load them into the content type.

I have also created a view to show the data from content type "Orders"

What i want:
Now i just want a logic either through "View" level or through the code.

so when the store's user (with username user1234) logs into the system, then the logic checks if the user username matches with the field StoreID (from content type "Orders") and then show the store's specific orders to the specific user not all the orders.

Comment: Have you tried in the view to create a filter for StoreID and add the value of the user's name via tokens? (You could also use contextual filters for this.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit of how to add StoreID to the username via a token. I am sorry I am new at the drupal